# mysql.connector.connect doesn't seem to have persistent connection through functions

Tags: mysql, flask, mysql-connector-python

Im having a little problem when using mysql in python with Flask framework. I have set up a function(`get_db()`) to connect to the database once a request and serve the same connection to functions requesting it later on(within the same request).

```
import mysql.connector #mysql-connector-python==8.0.12

def get_db():
if 'db' not in g:
    try:
        click.echo("Trying to connect")
        cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='stack', password='overflow',
                          host='127.0.0.1',
                          database=DB_NAME)
        g.db = cnx
        return g.db
    except mysql.connector.Error as err:
        if err.errno == errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:
            click.echo("Connection failed! Check username and password")
        elif err.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
            click.echo("Database does not exist")
        else:
            click.echo("Unknown error: {} ".format(err))
    else:
        cnx.close()
    # Connection to db cannot
    # be established.
    # click.echo("Will exit from database")
    exit(1)

click.echo("Using existing connection")
return g.db
```

In other functions I use it like this:

```
(...)
cnx = get_db()
cursor = cnx.cursor()
(...)
```

The first function that uses the database works fine. Then when another one tries to connect the `cursor` failes because `cnx` doesn't have a connection:

`raise errors.OperationalError("MySQL Connection not available.")`

Does anyone have a way to handle this?

One solution is to create the connection again for each function but for sake of performance I rather reuse a connection if possible.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I have currently ended up with involves a `reconnect` at each time a method needs the db connection.

I don't know if this will get the overhead a `connect()` get's but it is suitable for the current use case.

The code will look like this:

```
def get_db():
if 'db' not in g:
    try:
        cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='tom', password='jerry',
                          host='127.0.0.1',
                          database=DB_NAME)
        g.db = cnx
        click.echo("Returns new connection")
        return g.db
    except mysql.connector.Error as err:
        if err.errno == errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:
            click.echo("Connection failed! Check username and password")
        elif err.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
            click.echo("Database does not exist")
        else:
            click.echo("Unknown error: {} ".format(err))

cnx = g.db
cnx.reconnect() <--- Doing a reconnect each time
return cnx
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use pooling : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connection-pooling.html

import mysql.connector

```
conf = {"user":"username", "password":"*****", host="hostname"}
pool_cnc = mysql.connector.connect(pool_name="my_pool", **conf)

# Take one connection using the name of the pool:
cnc1 = mysql.connector.connect(pool_name = pool_cnc.pool_name)
cnc1.is_connected()

# Should output True
```

At the given link there is also an example about the explicitly pooling connection